# Overriding a method with try except block

Tags: python-3.x, odoo

Following is an inbuilt method in Odoo for handling exceptions:

```
class HttpRequest(WebRequest):
    def _handle_exception(self, exception):
       """Called within an except block to allow converting exceptions
       to abitrary responses. Anything returned (except None) will
       be used as response."""
       try:
            return super(HttpRequest, self)._handle_exception(exception)
       except SessionExpiredException:
            redirect = None
            req = request.httprequest
            if req.method == 'POST':
                request.session.save_request_data()
                redirect = '/web/proxy/post{r.full_path}'.format(r=req)
            elif not request.params.get('noredirect'):
                redirect = req.url
            if redirect:
                query = werkzeug.urls.url_encode({
                   'redirect': redirect,
                })
                return werkzeug.utils.redirect('/web/login?%s' % query)
        except werkzeug.exceptions.HTTPException as e:
            return e
```

I need to override this method and add more functionality inside `if redirect:` like this:

```
  if redirect:
      query = werkzeug.urls.url_encode({ 'redirect': redirect, })
      if 'web' in redirect:
           return werkzeug.utils.redirect('/web/login?%s' % query)
      else:
           return werkzeug.utils.redirect('/login?%s' %   query)
```

How can we do this?

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#unittest.mock.patch

Comment: Check the returned value.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this using plain old Pythonic inheritance, for example inside your modules model create a `http_inherit.py` file and inherit like this:

```
from odoo.http import HttpRequest

class InheritHttpRequest(HttpRequest):
  def _handle_exception(self, exception):
    ...
    ...
    if redirect:
      query = werkzeug.urls.url_encode({ 'redirect': redirect, })
      if 'web' in redirect:
        return werkzeug.utils.redirect('/web/login?%s' % query)
      else:
        return werkzeug.utils.redirect('/login?%s' %   query)
```

Don't forget to import that file to your module **init**.py. You can call super if you need to call the the original `_handle_exception` function, or you can just paste the whole original function in your inherited function and add extra functionalities. When you install this module, the functionalities of `_handle_exception` will be according to your inherited function.